# Why does passing a javascript function from PHP sometimes execute and sometimes not?

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload

I am uploading a file to PHP and want to return errors in an alert or better yet in a div element. It seems that when I do not use alert, the function always fails to produce the desired result. Although pressing ctrl-F5 (chrome) to bypass caching sometimes works, but sometimes the following console message is shown:

> writers.php:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: phpReturn is not defined

**JS call to PHP**

```
$('#writers').on('submit', function () {
    if (beforeSubmit()) {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    } else return false;
});
```

This works just fine.

**RelevantPHP error handler**

```
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $UploadDirectory . $NewFileName);
    finfo_close($finfo);
    if ($mime_type != 'application/pdf') {
        unlink($UploadDirectory . $NewFileName);
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>phpReturn('File MUST be a PDF!');</script>";
    }
```

**JS function called from PHP**

```
function phpReturn(errmsg) {
    if (errmsg != undefined) {
        alert(errmsg);
        $("#errmsg").text(errmsg).css({ 'display': 'block' });
    }
    window.location.href = "http://writers-tryst.ron-tornambe.com/#/writers";
```

It is a little tricky to test this behavior. You need to rename a non-PDF file to one with a PDF extension. Here is the [test site](http://writers-tryst.ron-tornambe.com/#/writers).

Comment: Why not return json data had just interpret that from your static javascript page? I wouldn't echo your javascript from the php side.

Comment: Shouldn't your submit handler cancel the default submit behaviour in all cases (not just in the else)? Otherwise you'll be doing an Ajax submit *and* a standard form submit, which (depending on what action you've specified in the form) could make the page reload.

Comment: @Rasclatt you make a good point. I started out doing that but thought I found a quick and dirty solution. Of course, it turns out I wasted more time than I hoped to save. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Yeah, it kind of sounds like that function is not being found sometimes, so it may be better just to return some data and handle it that way. Probably save yourself more hassle

Comment: I have relearned an age-old lesson - "there is never time to do it right, but always time to do it over!"